# Why has it become a formidable task to book an affordable hotel in Vancouver BC two weeks in advance?

Tags: bookings, hotels, price, vancouver

I have been trying to find a hotel online in Vancouver BC two weeks in advance (for July 17) and web sites are showing 85% of rooms are taken, leaving only rooms in the $240-$550 per night range, most of them out by the airport or in other remote places.

I checked the Vancouver BC events calendar, and all it shows is a charity regatta raising money for Easter Seals...

Six or so years ago and before there seemed to be abundant hotels in Vancouver BC, available for more like $50-80. I get that there may be inflation and variation but this seems extreme. So now that we have a supposed recession, the whole city is full of travellers and many are paying 2-6 times as much per night? What's going on?

Might it be useful to telephone hotels to book directly? Are the web sites charging finder's fees, so they only give some of their rooms to the sites?

Comment: Beds from 20 USD, rooms from 50. For the 17th of July: https://www.hotelscombined.com/Hotels/Search?destination=place:Vancouver&radius=0km&currencyCode=USD&checkin=2015-07-17&checkout=2015-07-18&Rooms=1&adults_1=2&pageSize=15&pageIndex=0&sort=MinRate-asc&showSoldOut=false&HotelID=&mapState=expanded%3D0

Comment: Thanks @MastaBaba. That's a good site. Studying the results though, even there I only see one hotel shown that's below $220/night near the city, (it looks like a good find though - Budget Inn Patricia Hotel). They're mostly hostel beds. My real question of course is what on Earth has changed in the last several years, or is there something odd going on in Vancouver?

Comment: Several of the hostels seem to provide single-occupancy rooms at reasonable enough prices. And, you know, beggars can't be choosers. Anyway, speculating on the reason the prices are high, is this not simply due to most hotels being full or nearly full, possibly because... it's the middle of high season? If you search for accommodation several months away, prices are much lower.

Comment: @MastaBaba Well, that could be - that's what I'm asking, in case people know more than I do. I don't remember ever seeing such high prices and low availability in Vancouver before.

Comment: I was trying to do s o for vancouver a couple of weeks ago, and it was almost impossible.  Turns out it was the football (womens) world cup final.  Perhaps there's another event on the 17th that may cause you problems.

Comment: As soon as the WC was over, the hostels suddenly became a lot more acecssible. If you are in the Samesun, I'm there on the 16th :)

Comment: Hmm. I've found a One Direction concern and a folk music festival on my dates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not constructive.

Comment: While limited to one aspect of the economy, [here is an article](http://business.financialpost.com/personal-finance/mortgages-real-estate/how-skyrocketing-vancouver-home-prices-are-fuelling-anger-towards-foreign-buyers) discussing how, over the preceding 5 years (2010-2015), home prices in Vancouver have skyrocketed. It is quite possible that other prices are rising to match, that what you are witnessing is not a coincidental event, and simply the economy and rising prices in the BC city itself.

Comment: @CGCampbell Hmm, that's interesting. Thank you. (I sure hope that's not it). I find this topic interesting and seems on topic to me, as hotel availability is a major factor in my ability and desire to travel someplace, as hotel price can divide down how long (or even if) I can afford to stay in a place. In the past I've occasionally run into this, but it's always been some really popular/busy time for the place (e.g. during a festival in Stockholm), while even places like London and Paris I've not had quite such problems finding an affordable hotel.

Comment: The simple answer is: Chinese money. Postpone your travel until the real estate bubble finally pops.